# Jpanel form no puede abrir un jframe form

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas para hacer la pregunta menos confusa dire que tengo un jpanel form, dos jframe form, jframe1 y jframe2.

En el jframe1 utilizo este codigo para llamas o insertar(no se como expresarlo) el jpanel form con boton:

```
Panel panelD = new Panel();
    panelD.setSize(1240,465); 
    panelD.setLocation(0,0); 

    PanelLab.removeAll(); 
    PanelLab.add(panelD,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    PanelLab.revalidate();
    PanelLab.repaint();
```

Esto funciona y el jframe1 muestra el jpanel, el problema es que este jpanel tiene un boton con el cual quiero abrir el jframe2, pero al presionarlo no sucede nada, uso este codigo:

```
private void btnAñadirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    frame2 v = new frame2();
    v.setVisible(true);
}
```

No se si hice algo mal (PD: tengo algo de sueño).

Disculpen las molestask, me di cuenta que estaba llamando otro Panel form que no era, soy idiota, perdon hacerles perder el tiempo.

Comment: Deberias poner el codigo de como añades ese segundo frame.

Comment: El segundo frame no quiero añadirlo, quiero abrirlo como una nueva ventana, pero al presionar el boton no se abre. No se si tendra que ver por que es un jpanel dentro de un jform (en este caso el jframe1).

Comment: Imagino que a lo que se refiere @chuchip es que añadas el código de como quieres abrir el segundo frame (si por ejemplo es con un botón, como comentas, añade la parte con el listener que ejecuta el codigo para abrir el nuevo frame).

Comment: Ya lo actualize, pero como digo solo es un boton con el tipico codigo para abrir un jframe form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun lo que he entendido necesitas crear un segundo frame, cuando pulses el botón en el primer frame, te añado este fragmento de código que espero te ayude.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creamos el primer frame
    Frame frame = new Frame();

    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //Creamos el panel
    Panel panelD = new Panel();
    panelD.setSize(400, 400);
    panelD.setLocation(0, 0);

    panelD.setVisible(true);

    //Creamos el boton
    Button btn1 = new Button("Abre segundo frame");
    btn1.setSize(50, 50);
    btn1.setLocation(10 , 10);

    btn1.setVisible(true);

    //Añadimos boton al panel
    panelD.add(btn1);

    //Añadimos el panel al frame
    frame.add(panelD);

    //Creamos el Listener del boton
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //Creamos un segundo frame
            Frame frame2 = new Frame();

            frame2.setSize(300, 300);
            frame2.setLocation(200, 200);

            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```